# with jQuery, add class="hover" on hover, than, add element to the hovered element

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

I want I have few divs [up to 10], I want to automatically add one of it and show it when specific element hover, I think I can't add them all one by one to the elements and hide them all one by one, and display them again using `:hover`

Example:

```
<div class="info1">extra info1</div> <!-- Hidden by deffult -->
<div class="info2">extra info2</div> <!-- Hidden by deffult -->
<div class="info3">extra info3</div> <!-- Hidden by deffult -->
<div class="info4">extra info4</div> <!-- Hidden by deffult -->

<div class="bla">I want info #1</div>
<br />
<div class="bla">I want info #2</div>
<br />
<div class="bla hovered">I want info #3</div> <div class="info3">extra info3</div> <!-- there wasn't info3, but its appeared because of the hovering -->
<br />
<div class="bla">I want info #4</div>
<br />
```

I failed when i created this [[here]](http://jsbin.com/uduziz) because I don't need css's help in this one, also as you see, the `extra span` is not hidden on first load (In other words, It should be hidden on first load, and appears only onhover).

I think its better when I tried with `onmouseover="this.className='` with `.appendTo` such as the failed attempt, but I don't know the right way to use them together.

Any Ideas, Suggestions?

UPDATE: Guys, I really appreciate your help with the `:hover` solution that needs to put and hide the `span` inside the `div`.
but I need more flexible and professional solutions.

Comment: Please click the check mark next to one of the answers if it helped you so that future visitors can be helped by the answer.

Comment: I will as soon as I see the answer that I need, Or the closest one :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the spans to the divs:

```
<div class="bla">I want info #1<span class="info">extra info</span></div>
<div class="bla">I want info #2<span class="info">extra info</span></div>
<div class="bla">I want info #3<span class="info">extra info</span></div>
<div class="bla">I want info #4<span class="info">extra info</span></div>
```

and CSS does it :

```
.info {display: none;}
.bla:hover .info {display: inline}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YmYYc/)

**EDIT:**

A javascript function that uses the index to target the right element is probably the way to go here, something like this :

```
$(function() {
    var elems = $('[class^="info"]').hide().css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0, 
        left: 0,
        height: 30,
        width: 100
    });

    $('.bla').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var i = $(this).index('.bla');
        elems.eq(i).toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7tcU/)

Comment: Again, as I said before, it is really hard for me to put the `span` and hide it inside the `div` i can't do this for over 30 `div`

Comment: @MohamedSamir - I added a little something something to the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Add the spans to each div to start.  The css to hide them is:

```
`div.bla>span {display:none}`
```

With jquery:

```
$('div.bla').hover(function() {
  $('span', this).show();
}, function() {
  $('span', this).hide();
});
```

Alternatively you can just do this via html and css without any javascript although I'd suggest you change the divs to hyperlinks but it isn't necessary:

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ujQ5B/

```
<a class="blah">link<span>something</span></a>

<div class="blah">link<span>something</span></div>



a.blah>span {display:none}
a.blah:hover>span {display:inline}

div.blah>span {display:none}
div.blah:hover>span {display:inline}
```

Comment: I know I can use this method, but I need to create the `spans` out of the `divs` just like the example.
I think I don't need to use any `:hover` solution that needs `spans` go indside the `divs` :(